# Convertir df de fechas en inglés a español

Tags: pandas

Tengo un dataframe que viene con fechas en inglés (el sistema lo genera).   Logré cambiar el formato usando esta solución en [*geeksforgeeks*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-pandas-datetime-format-in-python/). Funciona, pero necesito que el output de la columna sea en formato en español para uso de mi Tableau o PowerBi, no obstante al convertirlo (convertir a fecha), se vuelve otra vez al formato en inglés.

```
datos = [['2022-12-31'], ['2021-09-30'], ['2022-01-31']]
df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns = ['Fecha en Ingles'])
df['Fecha Español']=df['Fecha Ingles'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

El resultado es:

```
    Fecha Ingles    Fecha Español
0   2022-01-20  20/01/2022
1   2022-02-18  18/02/2022
2   2022-03-15  15/03/2022
3   2022-04-25  25/04/2022
4   2022-07-28  28/07/2022
```

Convertir a fecha:

```
df[['Fecha Español']] = df[['Fecha Español']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Regresa a esto:

```
Fecha Ingles    Fecha Español
0   2022-01-20  2022-01-20
1   2022-02-18  2022-02-18
2   2022-03-15  2022-03-15
3   2022-04-25  2022-04-25
4   2022-07-28  2022-07-28
```

¿Cómo se puede hacer para que quede con fecha d/m/a?  Ya traté locale, pero no logro descifrar el código.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo esta opción. En primer lugar, tenemos que cambiar el formato de la columna 'Fecha Ingles' a 'datetime64'. A continuación, creamos una columna nueva con el formato deseado, de la siguiente manera.

```
dicc_datos = { '2022-05-09': 15.9,'2022-05-10': 13.8, '2022-05-11': 12.7, '2022-05-12': 24.2, '2022-05-13':36.8} 

# Convertimos el diccionario en un DataFrame
datos = pd.DataFrame([[key, dicc_datos[key]] for key in dicc_datos.keys()], columns=['Fecha', 'Valor'])
# Cambiamos el formato de la columna 'Fecha'
datos['as_date'] = pd.to_datetime(datos['Fecha'], format='%Y/%m/%d')

# Creamos una columna nueva con el formato que queremos
datos['formated_date']  = datos['as_date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
# Cambiamos el tipo de datos a datetime64
datos['formated_date'] = pd.to_datetime(datos['formated_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
datos .info()
```

Nos devuelve:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------         --------------  -----         
 0   Fecha          5 non-null      object        
 1   Valor          5 non-null      float64       
 2   as_date        5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 3   formated_date  5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 288.0+ bytes
```

A continuación, se podría eliminar las columnas 'Fecha' y 'as_date' y  renombrar la columna 'formated_date'

Comment: Gracias, no comprendo de dónde sale la columna valor.  el formated_date es un objeto no una fecha.

Comment: Lo que pide el OP es que la columna con el formato día, mes, año sea de tipo `datetime64`, tu respuesta devuelve una columna `object` y es interpretada como `string`

Comment: Efectivamente, me faltaba una última sentencia para cambiar el formato de la columna 'formated-date' a datetime64. He modificado el script anterior.

Comment: En la sentenci para crear el DataFrame partiendo del diccionario, en el argumento '...columns=['Fecha', 'Valor'], estamos asociando  el nombre 'Fecha' a la columna con las keys del diccionario, y 'Valor? a las columnas con los values del diccionario.